# How to get stdev of subset of close data in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to Tradingview's Pine script and I can't seem to find the answer by googling. Suppose I want to compute the standard deviation of say the past 60 values for the closing price of a stock, but skip the the most recent 20 closing prices. In other words, I want to compute stdev (or some other function) on a total of 40 data points, starting 60 data points ago and not using the most recent 20 points. I assumie there is some way to "slice" the close series to get these 40 data points, but I have been unable to find this. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("Subset StdDev", overlay=true)

src                         = input(close, type=input.source)
var int         total_bars  = input(60)                             // Starting point, number of bars back
var int         datapoints  = input(40)                             // Number of datapoints from starting point to perform stddev calculation on

var float[]     a_values    = array.new_float()
var float       stddev      = na

array.push(a_values, src)                                           // add value for current bar to the end of the array

if array.size(a_values) > total_bars                                // array size > 60 ?
    array.shift(a_values)                                           // remove first element to keep array size at 60
    stddev := array.stdev(array.slice(a_values, 0, datapoints))     // calculate stddev for first 40 datapoints in the array

// plot a stddev band on the current candle, using 40 datapoints (from 60 bars ago to 20 bars ago)
plot(src + stddev)
plot(src - stddev)
```